# Can 4-20mA transmitters send through a 1kOhm resistor?

Tags: resistors, sensor, adc, transmitter, 4-20ma

I have a 4-20mA sensor at work and I wonder if it's possible if a 4-20mA transmitters send through a 1kOhm resistor?

I guy I talked to said that 4-20mA normaly can't send through 1kOhm because it's to high resistance.

So what is true? Is it common that most of the industrial sensors (12/24V) cannot send 4-20mA through a 1kOhm resistor or more?

Comment: At 20mA a 1k resistor will drop 20V, so the 12V sensors surely can't. The 24V ones might, but it'll be close to the limit.

Comment: @Unimportant Do you have a suggestion to protecting 4-20mA reciever from > 4V voltage? If I can't use a 1kOhm resistor. What should I do then?

Comment: Re, "protecting..receiver from > 4V" 4V _where?_ I.e., between what two points in the circuit are you measuring the voltage that you wish not to exceed 4V? If it's between the input terminals of the receiver, then you can't control that voltage. A "receiver" in a current loop will be driven by a _current source._ The receiver itself will determine the voltage between its terminals when driven with any given, constant current.

Comment: @SolomonSlow In this case, I'm measure over a 150 Ohm resistor and the ADC want 0 to 3.3v (STM32). But in reality, I will only get between 0.7V and 3.0V. That's good enought because the ADC is 16 bit. But I need to protect the 150 Ohm from higher voltage above 4 Volt, e.g 24V. I planning to use a PTC resistor, but not sure if it will be fast enogth to stop the fast current.

Comment: Why do you expect the ADC to see 24 volts? Can you draw the circuit? It's tough to understand what you are picturing.

Comment: It sounds as if maybe you don't trust the transmitter to limit the current to 20mA. Is that right? I can think of ways to deal with that, but I'm not a EE, so I can't claim to know any _good_ ways to deal with it. If that's really what you're asking, then you might get some answers if you edit your question text to be more explicit.